# issue scanning a directory on a mac in python

Tags: python, operating-system

Pulling my hair out it should be a simple function to iterate and list entries in a dir

```
 import os 

 def get_original_dir(target_dir):
     subfolders = [f.path for f in os.scandir(target_dir) if f.is_dir()]
     for target_dir in list(subfolders):
         subfolders.extend(get_original_dir(target_dir))
     return subfolders

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     selected = input("Input target dir: ")
     print get_original_dir(selected)
```

It is my first time coding on a mac I am wondering if I am missing something ? I execute the script and it runs gives me the prompt I input the following

Error is

```
 /Users/kyle/PycharmProjects/inmateTest

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/kyle/PycharmProjects/testPython/main.py", line 19, in <module>
     selected = input("Input target dir: ")
   File "<string>", line 1
     /Users/kyle/PycharmProjects/inmateTest
     ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I started with os.walk() I will reword

Comment: You need to return `subfolders`, not `print` it, so that `subfolders.extend()` will combine them.

Comment: Use `print` in the `main` code.

Comment: still didnt work same error updated to show the new code

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? In Python 3 `print` is a function, it needs parentheses around the arguments.

Comment: If you're using Python 2, you need to use `raw_input()`.

Comment: That was the issue had the wrong python environment